# Error : int cannot be converted to String

Tags: java

public  int GCD(int  num1 ,  int num2)
    {
        int gcd =1;

```
     for(int i = 1; i <= num1 && i <= num2; i++)
    {
        if(num1%i==0 && num2%i==0)
            gcd = i;
   }
     return gcd;

}
```

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:

```
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
     int num2 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());


     if (jButton1.isEnabled()) {
        System.out.println("Add Button is pressed");
    }
    if (!jButton1.isEnabled()) {
        System.out.println("Add Button is not pressed");
    }

        System.out.println("number 1 is: "+ num1);

          System.out.println("number 2 is: "+ num2);

       "this line give error"   jTextField4.setText(GCD(num1,num2));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

setText expect a String, convert your int to string

```
jTextField4.setText("" + GCD(num1,num2));
```

Comment: public  String GCD(int  num1 ,  int num2)
    {
        int gcd =1;
 
         for(int i = 1; i <= num1 && i <= num2; i++)
        {
            if(num1%i==0 && num2%i==0)
                gcd = i;
       }
         return Integer.toString(gcd);
         
  
    
    } now it is working fine

Comment: @MustafainRehmani don't modify your gcd method to return string, it's not a good practice, a gcd method should return an Integer or long.